# What is the meaning of the output of the command 'sensors'?

Tags: cpu, temperature

I have installed the package 'lm-sensors' and I use the command 'sensors' to check the temperature of my CPU. The output of the command is something like this:

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +52.5°C  (crit = +93.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +46.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 1:       +48.0°C  (high = +90.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)

dell_smm-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Processor Fan: 3000 RPM
CPU:            +52.0°C  
Other:          +44.0°C  
Other:          +45.0°C
```

What does virtual mean here? What is 'isa' and 'acpitz'? Which one is the real temperature of the CPU?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Management_Mode:

> SMM is a special-purpose operating mode provided for handling system-wide functions like power management, system hardware control, or proprietary OEM designed code.

`dell_smm-virtual-0` is your CPU fan, managed by your system firmware.

`acpitz-virtual-0` is the temperature sensor near/on your CPU socket. This sensor can be unreliable.

`coretemp-isa-0000` measures the temperature of the specific cores.

If you have an Intel device, the CPU sensor and motherboard sensor should **generally be accurate, or close to each other's readings.** Many AMD CPUs have faulty onboard sensors that heavily conflict with the motherboard readings.

Also, given that you have a laptop, and a firmware-controlled fan, a) fan control is most likely not possible, and b) your CPU temperatures are perfectly fine.

Comment: How did you find out `acpitz-virtual-0` is the temperature sensor near/on the CPU socket? Is it always so? Would you mind providing the document link? I'm also learning about it today.

Comment: What about `package id 0` in the CPU core temperature sensor output? On my system, it is above the temperature readings for the 4 cores, and is always a higher number than any of the cores. It's generally closer to the CPU fan sensor temperature (`pch_skylake-virtual-0`) than the core temperatures.

Answer (score 13):

Sensors is reporting values found in Linux virtual file system directory:

```
/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp
```

You can find them out yourself (even if Sensors isn't installed) using:

```
$ paste <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/type) <(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp) | column -s $'\t' -t | sed 's/...$/.0°C/'
INT3400 Thermal  20.0°C
pch_skylake      -47.0°C
SEN1             52.0°C
SEN2             48.0°C
SEN3             55.0°C
SEN4             58.0°C
B0D4             54.0°C
x86_pkg_temp     54.0°C
```

Notice the `pch_skylake` sensor has gone crazy. Whilst researching the problem I found this question and posted this answer.